# How to solve HTTPSConnectionPool(host='graph.facebook.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url

Tags: python

I am trying to post something on Facebook

```
def make_post():
    caption = post_caption()
    url = (
        f"https://graph.facebook.com/{config.page_id}/photos?"
        f"caption={caption}&access_token={config.token}"
    )
    files = {
        'image': open(pimage, "rb")
    }
    if config.dry_run:
        return dummy_response
    response = requests.post(url, files=files)
    return response.json()
```

but it gave me this error

`HTTPSConnectionPool(host='graph.facebook.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:  (Caused by NewConnectionError('urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001AD174AA5B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))`

I have searched here in stackoverflow but I didn't find anything that works sorry I am new to this site, if I did anything wrong.